# Intern coverage not including unloaded sources

Tags: javascript, code-coverage, intern, istanbul

When **Intern** tests don't load source files (0% covered), they don't show up in the (lcov) coverage report (running in nodejs).

Typically a problem JS tools struggle with, I think.

E.g. Jest has a [simple workaround](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1211).

I'm looking for the simplest workaround for intern, ideally with v3.

- Since Intern uses `istanbul` under the cover, wonder if [`--include-all-source`](https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul/issues/767) flag works and can be passed easily?
- Is there a standard recipe to make the loader aware of all files?
- I have files that don't load well in nodejs too, can they be included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a look at the Intern project itself and in the [config script](https://github.com/theintern/intern/blob/master/src/lib/common/config.ts) there is such an option called `coverage`, coverage is defined as:

> An array of file paths or globs that should be instrumented for code
>   coverage, or false to completely disable coverage. This property
>   should point to the actual JavaScript files that will be executed, not
>   pre-transpiled sources (coverage results will still be mapped back to
>   original sources). **Coverage data will be collected for these files
>   even if they’re not loaded by Intern for tests, ALLOWING A TEST WRITER TO SEE WHICH FILES HAVENT BEEN TESTED
>   writer to see which files *haven’t* been tested**, as well as coverage
>   on files that were tested. When this value is unset, Intern will still
>   look for coverage data on a global coverage variable, and it will
>   request coverage data from remote sessions. Explicitly setting
>   coverage to false will prevent Intern from even checking for coverage
>   data.  This property replaces the `excludeInstrumentation` property
>   used in previous versions of Intern, which acted as a filter rather
>   than an inclusive list.

Sorry for the uppercase, where just suppose to highlight the sentence.
`coverage` uses [glob](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob) just as istanbul does, so you could specify something like `coverage: ['src/**/*.js']`.

I realize this because Intern itself uses [this configuration](https://github.com/theintern/intern/blob/master/src/lib/common/config.ts) to collect coverage and it seems to work for them.

Edit: As pointed in the comments, this features only appears in v4 of intern.

Comment: The `coverage` option is the proper way to enable coverage in Intern 4, and will show coverage data for everything that matches the coverage glob(s). There isn't a built-in analog for Intern 3; it will only show coverage for files that are loaded.

Comment: Exactly as I said

Comment: I had a bit more to say there, but hit Enter early. :)

Comment: Wished there was an easy workaround in Intern3, but happy with this answer. Thank you both.

Comment: I will look a bit further and update my answer if I find a way of injecting something over istanbul or intern